# Dynamic type casting in python

Tags: python

I have 2 dicts:

```
dicts1 = {'field1':'', 'field2':1, 'field3':1.2}
dicts2 = {'field1':123, 'field2':123, 'field3':'123'}
```

I want to convert each value in `dict2` to be the same type as the corresponding value in `dict1`, what's the quickest pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: Interesting problem. Can we assume that such a conversion will always be possible? E.g. `dict2["field3"] = "foo"` would cause a problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming they're compatible types:

```
for k, v in dicts1.iteritems():
    try:
        dicts2[k] =  type(v)(dicts2[k])
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
        pass # types not compatible
    except KeyError as e:
        pass # No matching key in dict
```

Comment: It's nice how `type(v)(dicts2[k])` does exactly what we expect it to do. In which case are `TypeError` and `ValueError` respectively raised ?

Comment: int('bob') raises ValueError - can't remember why I put TypeError now tho' :(

Comment: @JonClements: something like `list(3)` would raise a TypeError; so would `int(3j)`, etc.

Comment: @DSM bingo - I knew there was a reason to put it, I was just drawing a blank as to why... thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This one liner will do it - but it does not check for type errors:

```
dicts1 = {'field1':'', 'field2':1, 'field3':1.2}
dicts2 = {'field1':123, 'field2':123, 'field3':'123'}

print {k : type(dicts1[k])(dicts2[k]) for k in dicts2}
```

This will also do it - and may be more readable for some:

```
print {k : type(dicts1[k])(v) for (k,v) in dicts2.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic is the answer for dynamic type conversion.

If type of values of `dicts1` is going to be a reference for the type of values in `dict2`, it's generally a good idea to convert dicts1 into a class that extends to `pydantic.BaseModel`

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class dicts1(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: int
    field3: float

dicts2 = dict(dicts1(**{'field1':123, 'field2':123, 'field3':'123'}))
print(dicts2)
```

output: {'field1': '123', 'field2': 123, 'field3': 123.0}